# Mostrar fotos de varias páginas correlativas con Ajax- Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

primero muchas gracias por este espacio para poder resolver las dudas en programación. Soy súper nueva en esto y me hace falta una manita.
Os cuento, hago una llamada ajax desde una vista Artículos/edit, donde, según el nº de página que selecciono, me salen las fotos incluidas en dicho artículo. Hasta aquí bien, todo funciona perfecto. Pero necesito que salgan también las fotos de las 2 páginas siguientes. Las tablas son Artículos y Fotos, se relacionan a la tabla Páginas con claves foráneas page_id, article_id. Pensé que desde la llamda Ajax podría hacerlo, pero con el código que puse salen los números de página bien, pero las fotos salen repetidas las que hayan seleccionadas en el select. Se que debo hacerlo en el controlador, pero ya no se cómo hacerlo.

Aquí está mi llamada Ajax:

```
  var urlajax = "{{route('photos_article2' )}}";
                $.ajax({
                    url: urlajax,
                    type: 'GET',
                    data:{
                        page_id:$('#page_id').val(),
                        article_id:{{$article->id}}
                    },
                    success: function (obj) {
                        var opcion_seleccionada = parseInt($('#page_id option:selected').text());
                        for(opcion_seleccionada=1;opcion_seleccionada<3;opcion_seleccionada++) {
                            document.getElementById("img_ajax2").innerHTML+=opcion_seleccionada+obj;
                        }
                    }
                });
´´´

Y aquí mi función en el controlador:
```

```
public function photos_ajax2(){
    $photos=Photo::where('page_id', $_GET['page_id'])->get();

    $article_id= $_GET['article_id'];
    return view('partials.photos_article2', compact('photos', 'article_id'));
}
```

```
Muchas gracias!
```

Answer (score 0):

lo más sencillo que se me ocurre sin hacer demasiadas modificaciones, es cambiar la consulta de Eloquent, es decir:

Si ahora tienes:

```
$photos=Photo::where('page_id', $_GET['page_id'])->get();
```

Si eso te vale, y lo único que quieres, es añadir a esa variable `$photos` las imágenes del `page_id` anterior y posterior, modificaría esa consulta y ya está:

```
//Creamos un array con los numeros de page_id que te interesan:
$aux = array();
$page_actual = (int) $_GET['page_id'];
array_push($aux, $page_actual - 1);
array_push($aux, $page_actual + 1);

//La consulta ahora quedaría:
$photos=Photo::whereIn('page_id', $aux)->get();
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Oh, k buena pinta hace tu respuesta. La probaré y te confirmo jmarrdiaz, muchísimas gracias!!